# Confluence REST API error when creating a page

Tags: python, rest, confluence

My code to create a page on Confluence with their REST API:

```
import requests

url = "https://<some confluence>/wiki/rest/api/content/"

data = {"type":"page",
        "title":"REST API test",
        "space":{"key":"<some space>"},
        "body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>Some body text</p>",
                "representation":"storage"}}}

headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

r=requests.post(url, auth=("admin", "admin"), data=data, 
headers=headers)
```

This produces an internal server error [500], and similarly changing the POST to a PUT produces a method not allowed error [405].

How can I create a page on Confluence? Any method is fine, does not strictly have to be with Python.

Comment: Have you tried with `url = "https://<domain>/rest/api/content/"`? All of the examples I've found do not have wiki within them.

Comment: If your work with an local test instance ("atlas-run" or "atlas-run-standalone") the default url is http://localhost:1990/confluence. Just make sure its not the wrong url.